# JiraTestResultReporter Jenkins plugin not creating issues automatically

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have a sample Java code in Github which has 5 test cases out of which 2 will fail. I have a Maven project in jenkins which will create issues for these 2 failed tests while building the  project. I'm using JiraTestResultReporter plugin. I have Jira credentials in Configure System Page in Jenkins. Even when I select the "Auto Raise Issues" option, Issues are not getting created. However I was able to create issues from Test results page in Jenkins(So communication is not a problem)manually by clicking "+" next to failed test. Strangely I dont see anything related to JiraTestResultReporter in console output of the job.

[Manually I can create issue in Test results Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuGxw.jpg)

Maven Project
Jenkins Version 2.89.4 (Bitnami AMI on AWS)
JiraTestResultReporter version 2.0.6

What am I missing ??